# store data from dropdown menu & relationship - laravel 5.2

Tags: forms, laravel, dropdown

How can i store my data inside db using {!! form !!} builder?
controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = \DB::table('categories')->lists('title', 'id');
    return view('dash.reports.create')->with('categories', $categories);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required', ]);

    Report::create($request->all());

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Report added!');

    return redirect('dash/reports');
}
```

my view:

```
        {!! Form::label('category_id', trans('reports.category_id'), ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::select('category', 
            (['0' => 'Select a Category'] + $categories), 
            null, 
            ['class' => 'form-control']) 
        !!}
            {!! $errors->first('category_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
```

when i press button action return me blank page, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a form, so you're not submitting data to the correct page. You're sending a POST request to the same URL that you used to access the form, which is probably not what you want.

This guide will show you how to set up a Laravel form that points at a controller method which will allow you to capture input, validate it, and store it in the database.
http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/02/09/creating-a-contact-form-in-laravel-5-using-the-form-request-feature/

Comment: I use https://packagist.org/packages/appzcoder/crud-generator for crud generator and works well!
with this:
{!! Form::number('category_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
it works, but when i change for retrieve my data as dropdown menu (ie. category with foreign) It seems not to work

where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

solved
view:

```
{!! Form::select('category_id', $category, null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $category = Category::lists('title','id');
    return view('dash.reports.create')->with('category', $category);
}
```